# Is it possible to display the Navigation Menu without using Walker_Nav Class

Tags: walker, twitter-bootstrap

I want to ask is it possible to display menus and submenus without using Walker Nav Class? I'm just to happen when I download a free theme using bootstrap and I do not see a start_el for navigating the menus and submenus. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. The `wp_nav_menu()` will automatically use the `Walker_Nav_Menu`  Class by default. It's not necessary to use a custom walker for a drop down menu ( or submenu ). The `wp_nav_menu()` accepts a few arguments and one of those is `depth`. If the depth argument is set to 1 then it will limit the menu to top level items.

Really, it's up to your theme to use CSS and style these dropdown menus so that they are functional.

Comment: Thanks, can we display the menu and submenus without using wp_nav_menu Class?

Comment: The theme would call the `wp_nav_menu()` function. You can statically add HTML items into the header, call the `wp_list_pages()` function. You can also query the items directly via `WP_Query` if you wish, loop and display them. If you're building or willing to modify the theme then you can do many things to display a menu or menu items. If it's not a theme you've put together or are willing to modify then you're dependent on however the theme handles menus and submenus.

Comment: @How_McGee, Thanks a lot..